# r apply function(x) over wilcox.text

Tags: r, function, loops, statistics

I have a "List of 6" data.frames (outliers are removed), variable is called:  lessoutliers

```
str(lessoutliers)
> str(lessoutliers_list)
List of 6 ... .... lots of output removed.
```

Up to now I have been running the wilcox.test on an individual data.frame, but how to loop through all 6 in one shot and report on all 6 ?  maybe using function()

```
wilcox.test(SPEND ~ TC_INDICATOR, mu=means["CONTROL"], conf.level=0.95,
            paired=F, data=Tableone)
```

So instead of using one Tableone and then running it again for Table2, Table3, etc... just loop of the List of 6 ?

I tried using lapply and function(), but I must messed up the syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `lapply` or `do.call` would require building a list of data frame names.  Another option would be to use a `for` loop and iterator over an array of data frame names. Beyond that, there isn't much that can be done if you don't show what you tried.

Comment: If they all have the same structure (here, variable names should suffice), you could use `lapply`. Something like `myTests <- lapply(lessoutliers, function(x), wilcox.test(SPEND ~ TC_INDICATOR, mu=means["CONTROL"], conf.level=0.95,
            paired=F, data=x))`

Comment: the list of tables names is inside the List of 6, each one is there ?   e.g.:  summary(lessoutliers$list1)

Comment: I removed the "," after function(x) and it seems to have worked, damn it :-)  that's very close to what I had.  It worked, question, if I do summary(lessoutliers$table1)  how can I loop through this 6 times ?

Comment: how does this work, by the way, how does function(x) know that ?

Comment: this use of function is called an anonymous function. It is thrown away after use. It takes a single argument which is the data.frame and is fed by `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks!  Just read a good howto and did some practice, now this makes total sense!